# Google Maps API search location and pin

Tags: api, google-maps

I am trying to put google maps on my browser and I am having trouble with APIs. What I am trying to do is have a searchbox with a map under it, where the user can put address and it will search near restaurants and pin them on the map. What I tried is searching the hole google and it just gets more confusing. I need help with this.

Answer (score 3):

I came across something similar not so long ago and stumbled upon this neat [jQuery Autocomplete Plugin](http://gerger.co/blog/2011/02/17/google-maps-api-v3-location-search-with-jquery-autocomplete-plugin/).

It autocompletes the location you type and searches for it, after which it focuses the map on that location. It doesn't however highlight the nearest restaurants/bars/etc., but you can easily place a marker if said location was found. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in using PHP, [this library](http://code.google.com/p/php-google-map-api/) will **greatly** help your journey. It saved me countless hours with the Google Maps API.

Comment: this was helpful, but I need a way to search and drop a pin on the map

Comment: You need the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#PlaceSearchRequests) and to get the places, and then you can put them on the map. The solution is more-involved than can be described on StackOverflow. I do this for pay for my customers.